# HTML: show &gt; in plain text

Tags: html

In HTML files, if I want the browser to show a special symbol, such as `>`, I can use the special escape character sequence `&gt;` and the browser will automatically transform it to `>`.

But what if I don't want it to be transferred into `>`? What if I happen to want the character sequence to be shown in plain text?

Comment: You need to find the code [HTML character codes](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html). The text will look like `Hello &#60;Strong&#62;`

Answer (score 5):

In order to have a character sequence not automatically rendered as a symbol, you can escape out the ampersand. This method is commonly used by instructional pages with lists of HTML symbols.

```
Source:  &gt;
Result:  >

Source:  &amp;gt;
Result:  &gt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ry-♦ for stating the obvious. I was so concerned about using raw string, I didn't realize what I was using is adequate already. Use `.textContent` property to render text as is. If you use something like `.innerHTML`, it will parse your text as HTML and apply escape sequences.

## Demo

```js
var str = "&gt;"

document.querySelector('body').textContent = str;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with template literals and everything to do with `textContent` vs. `innerHTML`. (Also, try ``<button onclick="alert(String.raw`&gt;`)">``.)